# broadcast the video realtime

Tags: javascript, webrtc, html5-video

Id like to broadcast the video realtime on different network(public) using webrtc. I am checking TannerGabrriel Broadcast code on github!
This is the  code :https://github.com/TannerGabriel/WebRTC-Video-Broadcast
Im new in javascript.. I usually use python php html but it make very hard for me to understand javascript for some reason. I tried the screen share but it takes the whole screen! I only want the video to be broadcast, And how do my viewer to watch it?

Html part

```
<video preload="auto" autoplay poster="./css/poster.jpg">
   <source src="./css/den.mp4" type="video/mp4"></source>
</video>
```

I got the JS from youtube but Id like to stream it online. realtime... tracking each movement on this video,,, fast forward , backward pause! go to 12:21

```
(function(){
        var video = document.getElementById('video'),
            vendorUrl = wind.URL || window.webkitURL;
            
        navigator.getMedia = navigator.getUserMedia ||
                            navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                            navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                            navigator.msGetUserMedia;
                            
        navigator.getMedia({
            video:true,
            audio:false
        }, function(stream){
            video.src =verndorUrl.createObjectURL(stream);
            video.play();
        }, function(error){
        
        });
    })();
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Ill edit my questio

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to broadcast a video, use `wrtc` on backend, with it single source can broadcast a video to multiple receiving ends. unlikely `wrtc` is an node js package and dont know what you're backend is made of